# how can I rotate a python turtle object

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need h_roof to rotate left 90 degrees. I have tried to use h_roof.degrees(90) but it does nothing. Here's my code

```
h_roof = turtle.Turtle()
h_roof.speed(0)
h_roof.shape("triangle")
h_roof.shapesize(stretch_len=18, stretch_wid=18)
h_roof.color("#233030")
```

I know i need to add something but i'm not sure what.

Comment: Try `h_roof.degrees(360)` and then `h_roof.left(90)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.left)

Turn turtle left by angle units. (Units are by default degrees, but can be set via the degrees() and radians() functions.) Angle orientation depends on the turtle mode, see mode().

```
turtle.left(90)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following functions. 
Object.right(angle) or object.left(angle)

```
turtle.right(90)
```

or

```
turtle.left(90)
```